# Drupal 8 select list first as default value

Tags: drupal, selectlist

Please, I want to know if there's a simple way in Drupal 8 to make a select list first value always as default value and delete "Select a value" line. 
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done by adding a List(text) field. After adding the values to your select list choose a default value from that select list as shown in the image below.

[Default value for select list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQSVr.png)

Under Manage Form Display choose select list. This should display the default value set and not 'Select a Value'. Hope this help.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer, Actually, I don't have a single default value, it depends on the user role, that's why I am looking to set always the value of the options because it differs from a user to another.